# How to extend the NavigationListItem control in SAPUI5?

Tags: custom-controls, sapui5

I want to extend the NavigationListItem control to accept sap.ui.core.Control objects in it's aggregation. I have created a separate file to extend the control and added a new aggregation called 'rows' with type sap.ui.core.Control in the metadata section. The extended control is getting called in the view, but it is not displaying any child controls which were added to the new aggregation 'rows'. Please advise, if I need to add anything more to the extension file.

Extension code:

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/Control",
               "sap/tnt/NavigationListItem"],
    function(Control, NavigationListItem) {
    "use strict";
    return NavigationListItem.extend("ajacontrolExt.control.NavigationCustomListItem", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {
            },
            defaultAggregation: "rows",
            aggregations: {
                rows: {
                    type: "sap.ui.core.Control",
                    multiple: true,
                    singularName: "row"
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code for your custom control. Also you probably have to write a new renderer that also renders the elements from your new aggregation

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the code in the query.

Comment: You have to tell UI5 how to render the new aggregation. For this you have to define/overwrite the inherited `render` method of the class. For a guide check https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/docs/controllibraries.md#the-control-renderer

Comment: You dont have a render method, and this one is not inherited. Plus you cant just change the aggregation type and expect the control to run properly ;)